# calling non static method from static method in console application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, static, console-application

I know there has been other question with this title. But I feel my scenario is different.

I am trying to create a console application which uses another project's service.
I have installed Unity for dependency injection. And here is the code

```
class Program
{
    private readonly IFooService _service;

    public Program(IFooService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unity = new UnityContainer();
        var unityConfig = new MyUnityConfig();
        unityConfig.RegisterTypes(unity);

        // need to call MyFunc
    }

    public void MyFunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        _service.ServiceFunc();
    }
}
```

And here is `MyUnityConfig` class

```
public class MyUnityConfig 
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        //repository registration
        container.RegisterType<IFooRepository, FooRepository>();

        //services registration
        container.RegisterType<IFooService, FooService>();

    }
}
```

I can't call `MyFunc` because it's *not static*. If I make `MyFunc` *static* I can't use `_service` because `_service` is *not static*. I could create new program object and create object of `FooService` that implements IFooService but then I would have to create new object of FooRepository which needs to be passed in FooService's constructor and the whole idea of dependency doesn't make sense.

And finally I *can't make Main non static* because then I would get `Program does not static 'Main' method for entry point` error

Ps: Feel free to change the title of question if my problem doesn't match the title. And correct me if my approach is wrong.

Comment: What's still unclear after reading your question is which instance of `Program` you *actually* want to call `MyFunc` on. Has *anything* created an instance yet? I don't see anything doing so at the moment. Perhaps you just need `Program program = unity.GetInstance<Program>();` or something like that? (I don't know anything about Unity, so you'd need to find the exact call.)

Comment: To call a non static function you need to use/create an instance where the non static function will be called. Otherwise it is impossible to call the function.

Comment: private static IFooService _service; will solve issue if there is no need of readonly

Comment: Just resolve instance of `Program` from your container, then call `MyFunc` on it (of course first register `Program` in container in `RegisterTypes`).

Comment: @JonSkeet unity or UnityContainer does not have GetInstance method. I am using UnityContainer whose runtime version is 4.0.30319

Comment: As I said, I haven't used Unity. *You* should do the research to find out how to ask the container to get an instance of a specific type. That's half the point of the container, so I'd expect that to be one of the first things shown in any tutorial - but it's up to you to do that research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with DI container - all instantiations involving types from container (such as `IFooService`) should go through container.

In your case, `Program` depends on `IFooService` and so should also be registered in container:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    //repository registration
    container.RegisterType<IFooRepository, FooRepository>();

    //services registration
    container.RegisterType<IFooService, FooService>();

    container.RegisterType<Program>();
}
```

And then resolved from container (which will also resolve all its dependencies, such as `IFooService`):

```
var unity = new UnityContainer();
var unityConfig = new MyUnityConfig();
unityConfig.RegisterTypes(unity);
var p = (Program)unity.GetService(typeof(Program));
p.MyFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks!! learned something new regarding unity container and dependecy injection